# Unable to perform web element operations in custom library of Robot Framework 3.1.2 and Python 3.7.4

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have a custom library in Robot Framework and I am trying to pass id of some web element and perform operation on the same.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class mylibrary:

    def get_webdriver_instance(self):
        return BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')

    def sendkeys_value(self,ele,value):
        driver = self.get_webdriver_instance()
        element = driver.find_element_by_id(ele)
        element.send_keys(value)
```

When call sendkeys_value in Robot Framework its throwing error as `Attribute Error: 'SeleniumLibrary' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'`

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `driver` object is a reference to the SeleniumLibrary itself, while it has a property `driver` itself, which is the actual selenium library. A lot of drivers repeated :) , it's probably easier to explain with an example:

```
driver = self.get_webdriver_instance().driver
```

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing. `driver` is not a reference to `SeleniumLibrary`, it's a reference to the webdriver object.